# Android Studio Shortcut to create new file/class

Tags: android-studio, android-shortcut

I know it is a very kindred question but want to know what the actual answer for it.

> What is the default keyboard shortcut to create a new file/class in Android studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, the shortcut is: `Alt` + `Insert`

Comment: It always helps to comment the actual command these keybindings invoke. This Alt-Insert doesnt do this on Linux AS in 2023.